# Mermaid JS keeping nodes level?

Tags: markdown, mermaid

I have a flowchart in mermaid JS that I'm trying to add dotted lines to. I've got the layout that I want, but whenever I add the dotted lines or any lines between the nodes the entire flowchart layout changes.

```
flowchart BT
    virtual[" "] --- 0["0"]
    x(["X"])
    subgraph virtual[" "]
        a[["A"]]
        b[["B"]]
        c[["C"]]
        x --- a
        x --- b
        x --- c
    end
```

[Removed image due to not having enough reputation, can be visualized in mermaid.live]

I want A,B and C to be connected like this:

```
flowchart LR
    A -.- B -.- C
```

[Removed image due to not having enough reputation, can be visualized in mermaid.live]

When I try to connect them, this is what I get:

[Removed image due to not having enough reputation, can be visualized in mermaid.live]

I've tried putting them in their own subgraphs but that didn't work either.